# What does gcc #define when compiling objective-c(++)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, gcc, g++

Is there some `#define` I can look at so that I know when to pull in `<OpenGLES/EAGL.h>`, for instance? Thanks!

Comment: FYI you can get a list of all of the predefined macros by running the command `cpp -dM /dev/null | sort`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
#if defined(__OBJC__) && defined(__cplusplus)
```

For Objective-C just leave off the `__cplusplus` part

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to determine this by running "gcc -v filename" and looking for the arguments to the "cc1" command (-DTHIS, -DTHAT, ...).